# Laravel ErrorException: Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload a file via axios api troughr Laravel. Below is the controller code but
I don't understand why Laravel tell me the variable name on line 24 is undefined.
It seems to me the variable is defined...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required'
]);

if($request->get('image'))
{
    $image = $request->get('image');
    $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
    \Image::make($request->get('image'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
}

$image= new FileUpload();
$image->image_name = $name;
$image->save();

return response()->json(['success' => 'You have successfully uploaded an image'], 200);
}
```

This is the line 24: `$image->image_name = $name;`

Comment: Post your line 24 code plz

Comment: $image->image_name = $name;

Comment: $image->image_name = $name; is this line 24??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make your variable in higher visibility scope :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
]);
 $name=''; // here you define your vaiable
if($request->get('image'))
{
    $image = $request->get('image');
    $name = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($image, 0, strpos($image, ';')))[1])[1];
    \Image::make($request->get('image'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
}

$image= new FileUpload();
$image->image_name = $name;
$image->save();

return response()->json(['success' => 'You have successfully uploaded an image'], 200);
}
```

more about variable scope in:

https://phppot.com/php/variable-scope-in-php/

Comment: He also need to check the file is an image on `validation `